# Public private key signing/encoding

Tags: ios, swift, jwt, public-key-encryption, private-key

I'm stuck trying to base64 encode a public private key. It looks like I can encode public and private keys separately with the [SwiftyRSA library](https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA).

My problem is that I can't put them together the way the [API JWT assertion](https://developer.box.com/v2.0/docs/authentication-with-jwt) should look (in RS256). I've read through plenty of documentation, but I'm having trouble trying to do the final task of having a base64 encoded variable.

I found the code below to be helpful. Essentially what I want to do is combine the public and private key into a token. This code is for javascript, but I can't seem to find something similar for Swift.

```
// First, let's try to use the top-level one-off methods.
jwt = new lib.JsonWebTokens();
 // Encode JWT token using 512-bit RSA signing algorithm.
token = jwt.encode( payload, "HS512", getPublicKey(), getPrivateKey() );
```

Would anyone be willing to look at this and tell me the one or two steps I'm missing?

Other details:
This is for the Box api

Thanks in advance!

--------------- EDIT -----------------------------------------------

I was able to implement the SwiftyRSA library. The example code is below. The output gives me a JWT assertion that works with the **jwt.io website**. However...(please read below code)

```
        do {
        // the keys
        let publicKey = try PublicKey(pemNamed: "public_key")
        let privateKey = try PrivateKey(pemNamed: "dec_private_key")

        // signing the base64url string
        let clear = try ClearMessage(string: encodedStuff, using: .utf8)
        let signature = try clear.signed(with: privateKey, digestType: .sha256)
        print(signature.data)

        // making the signature string base64url encoded
        let finalSig = signature.base64String.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "_")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "-")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "=", with: "")
        print("finalSig: ", finalSig)

        // encrypt the signature and make sure it's in base64url
        let dataToEncrypt = try ClearMessage(string: finalSig, using: .utf8)
        let encryptedData = try dataToEncrypt.encrypted(with: publicKey, padding: .PKCS1)
        let finalEncryptedData = encryptedData.base64String.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "_")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "-")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "=", with: "")
        print(finalEncryptedData)

        // concatenate assertion
        jwtAssertion = encodedStuff + "." + finalEncryptedData
        print("JWT Assertion: \(jwtAssertion)")

        // decrypt to see if it works
        let recodedBase64 = base64urlToBase64(base64url: finalEncryptedData)
        let theEncrypted = try EncryptedMessage(base64Encoded: recodedBase64)
        let clearMessage = try theEncrypted.decrypted(with: privateKey, padding: .PKCS1)
        // decode decrypted message
        let finalDecrypted1 = clearMessage.base64String
        let finalDecrypted2 = Data(base64Encoded: finalDecrypted1)
        let finalDecrypted3 = String(data: finalDecrypted2!, encoding: .utf8)
        print("finalDecrypted3: ", finalDecrypted3 ?? "no go!") //this gives you the finalSig (which is decrypted)



    } catch let thisError {
        print("An error has occurred!",thisError)
    }
```

It turns out I have to use base64url for each, which is only a matter of replacing some characters with other, etc. So, everything looks good and still works on the jwt website, but when I send it using the code below I get this error message:

> {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"OpenSSL unable to verify data: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line"}

I've followed all the steps on how to do this for the Box API, but it's just not working out. I'd really like to know what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: JWT.io lists some swift libraries, maybe they could help. You don't actually encode the private key; that needs to be kept, well, private. You do sign the token with the private key, which is why the JavaScript library needs you to provide the private key. swiftyRSA can both encrypt with a public key and sign with a private key, but these are separate operations you need to undertake in order to build a valid JWT

Comment: Thank you for providing clarity, Paulw11! So, what I want to do is encrypt the public key, sign it with the private key, then encode it using base64 encoding. At least, that's what I gathered from your explanation. I think that's actually doable using the [Apple library](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/Encryption.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH211-SW1).